# How to use javascript variable in <xsl:if test= condition

Tags: javascript, xslt

```html
<script language="JavaScript">
  var acct = "0";
</script>

<xsl:for-each select="acctdtls">
  <xsl:if test="@codacctno != acct)">

    <script language="JavaScript">
      acct = "<xsl:value-of select = '@codacctno'/>";
    </script>

  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

In which i have use "acct" as a java-script variable which i want to used in if statement. I have tried $acct and &acct but not succeed... Please suggest solution.

Comment: How to use javascript variable in <xsl:if test= condition

Comment: Are you using any framework (e.g. AngularJS)?

Comment: no, not using any framework.

Comment: There are a few XSLT processors that allow you to write extension functions in Javascript but in general there is no interaction between XSLT and Javascript, in your snippet you seem to have XSLT code that generates some HTML with an HTML script elements, the XSLT processor will simply generate HTML, the script code will not be executed by the XSLT processor. And HTML rendering and Javascript execution is then up to the browser in an additional and often completely separate step.

Comment: There are quite some frameworks that would make your life very easy. I suggest you Google for AngularJS which has a great approach and solution for binding variables and HTML contents. It is a little bit difficult at the beginning till you get the idea, and then... simply the sky is the limit.